# SpecialFolders with multiple versions of PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a means in PS2.0 of getting at some of the Special Folders that are not enumerated until later versions?
For example, `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("ProgramFilesX86")` works in PS5.0 but produces an enumeration error in PS2.0. I was thinking maybe there is a .NET based approach, but my Google fu has me thinking that even in .NET prior to Framework 4 there is no way, but that also seems like a pretty glaring oversight.

Comment: `[Environment]::GetFolderPath(...)` _is_ a .NET-based approach, using the framework version that the PowerShell version is built on. Unless you (a) have a later framework version installed on the same machine _and_ (b) somehow figure out a way to call into that later version (which sounds nontrivial, if it's feasible at all), you're out of luck.

Comment: @mklement0, that's pretty much what I was thinking, and afraid of. But, thanks for the verification. Time to change plans a bit.

Answer (score -1):

The first of the below commands returns 47 in PowerShell 5.1.1 on Windows 10 1803. In PowerShell 2.0 on the same system, it returns 23. If you removed the pipe to Measure-Object and the Count property dotted notation, it'll actually show the names of the folders you can use. That's the seconds of the the below commands.

```
([enum]::GetNames([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]) | Measure-Object).Count

([enum]::GetNames([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]) | Sort-Object) -join "`n"
```

PowerShell 2.0 Special Folders:

```
ApplicationData
CommonApplicationData
CommonProgramFiles
Cookies
Desktop
DesktopDirectory
Favorites
History
InternetCache
LocalApplicationData
MyComputer
MyDocuments
MyMusic
MyPictures
Personal
ProgramFiles
Programs
Recent
SendTo
StartMenu
Startup
System
Templates
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is can you get special folders no in the PS 2 enumeration somehow.  The OP is already aware that there are less enum options in PS 2 vs PS 5.